# php artisan migrate saying "nothing to migrate"

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-artisan, artisan-migrate

I've just got my MySQL database setup. When I run `php artisan migrate`, it creates the migrations table (which is empty) and then says "nothing to migrate". I have 3 migration files. I've tried `php artisan migrate:reset`, `php artisan migrate:refresh` and `php artisan config:cache`, but it still says the same thing. I've tried making a new database but the same comes from that. The empty migrations table is the only table in the database. Please help me fix this, thanks!

Comment: Where are your migrations located, what naming convention are you using, and can you post a sample migration?

Comment: @Jason I used `php artisan make:migration NAME` to make migrations. [Here](https://imgur.com/gYF3vbA) is a screenshot of the folder and [this](https://hastebin.com/peripomufu.xml) is the post migration.

Comment: Post your migration files

Comment: @AbderrahimSoubaiElidrissi Check the command above

Comment: *comment not command

Comment: Please put in your question the error output in the `/storage/logs/laravel.log` file. Before you do, delete everything in the log, THEN run your `php artisan migrate` command, and THEN copy and paste everything in the log. You can use http://pastebin.com/ if you like.

Comment: run php artisan migrate:status.. see Y - already migrate.. N - not yet. migration files should be in database/migrations.

Answer (score 0):

If you are altering a table, make sure you delete the information from the migrate table in your DB. I solved a similar problem by deleting the information from the migrate table in my DB.